# after GWT/js redirect, request.setAttribute does't work

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, gwt

In my site I have few languages to choice. I use a servlet, jsp to view, and GWT as a place where is localized button to action (treat it as js). In servlet I'm catching the subdomain which is the language like en, de, fr and so on (for instance en.mydomain.com will give string "en").
Because I use GWT I have to send parameter, to jsp with a current locale which I get from subdomain. 
the jsp parameter code looks like bellow

```
<meta name="gwt:property" content="locale=<%=request.getAttribute( "locale1" )%>">
```

and servlet send attribiute:

```
request.setAttribute("locale1", locale);
```

But in my site (GWT layer) you can change the language just by pushing the button with flag. What happens there? I replacing the subdomain from one language to another.
After push I redirect the url to new one with new subdomain

```
Window.Location.assign(Window.Location.createUrlBuilder()
    .setHost(newURL).buildString());
```

The url is correct after above action and then the action is walking into servlet where I get language from subdomain which is correct (the new one is fetched) and trying to setAttribute like above code.
But in jsp locale are not replaced. Just previous language still are there. No matter how many times I would perform the action the jsp will not replace the locale (mean en de fr ...)

**The question**: why it happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than passing locale as request attribute for each redirect or new browser window try it using `locale` as query string or both in combination. It might solve this issue.

Add below script in each `jsp` page.

```
<script>
    var search = location.search;
    if (search.indexOf("locale") == -1) {
        var lang = navigator.language != null ? navigator.language
                : navigator.browserLanguage;
        var lang = lang.replace("-", "_");
        document.write("<meta name='gwt:property' content='locale="+lang +"'>");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: we have locale as a subdomain so locale in query would be redundant

Comment: I haven't tested it because I have to code a lot to test it. Just try it. It might work.